# How create a custom dialog screen imageview android?

Tags: android, image

My application will load the bill `Image` up an `ImageView`.
Then I want to create a square `Frame`like when I want to crop an `Image`.
This `Frame`can be moved anywhere on the background of the application.
This `Frame`is similar to the magnifying glass.
When I want signed, I just click on the `Frame`, immediately it will enlarge the background area in the `Frame`, I just signed up on that.
My idea is so.
Now, I do not know how that create this `Frame`?
Can you help me?

Comment: Did you resolve this ?